# Bootstrap align label left of form-switch

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment

I am currently unable to align my label to the left of my switchbox. After looking at various stackoverflow pages, and browsing other websites, I am still unable to align my label to the left.

Please find below the snippet I have cut out unneeded code:

```
 <form method="POST" id="registration-form">
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="height" @click='imperialHeight()'>
     <label class="form-check-label" for="bmi">Imperial</label>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="form-check form-switch">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="weight-switch" @click='imperialWeight()'>
     <label for="weight-switch">Imperial</label>
   </div>
</form>
```

Please note that there is not any associated CSS.
I am using Bootstrap 5 and please see the screenshot below:
[Current Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfrSH.jpg)

Thank you for your time,
Alex

Comment: please mention the bootstrap version you are using, your complete file code, libraries/frameworks used in conjunction, a preview etc.

Comment: I will update now

Comment: @AdisonMasih changes have been made.

Comment: @AdisonMasih all the code being used is there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well with some CSS, we can get this job done.

```css
.form-switch {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDisabled" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDisabled">Disabled switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled" checked disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled">Disabled checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Also, please note that alignment and positioning are two different things. in this case, your question was about positioning instead.

when we say of alignment of text,
we generally refer to the `text-align` property.

```
.some_text {
  text-align: left;
}
```

so don't be confused between alignment and positioning.

### Update

For reducing the space between the label and the switch,
remove the `justify-content` property and add a `margin-right` to the label.

```css
.form-switch {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.form-switch label {
 margin-right: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDisabled" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDisabled">Disabled switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled" checked disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled">Disabled checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck31hg02/) for it

Comment: Mashih There is now quite a large gap between the label and the switch, how do I reduce this without it effecting the positioning?